# Rails 4 - Precompiled assets breaking my Bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm building a Rails app using Bootstrap for mobile scaling. When I deployed to Heroku, all my assets went missing. I thought that had been fixed in Rails 4, but anyway. I precompiled all the assets using 'rails_12factor'. Now all my images and styles are rendering just fine, but the dropdown menu inexplicably does nothing at all.

Am I doing something wrong in the compilation maybe? I went;

```
$ rake assets:precompile
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Asset Fix"
$ git push heroku master
```

...and my menu broke.

Here's what it looks like now; http://rocky-crag-1181.herokuapp.com/

Resize your browser to recreate the break.

```
Repository at; https://github.com/SoundBank/soundbank02
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined bootswatch.js:1 ----- I saw this error on console. Means on that page all js are loaded before the main jQuery file. put jQuery.js on top and then again clean the assets  and then precomile assets. Push the code. this error causes the dropdown menu not working.

Comment: Or you may have load jQuery twice on same page. so remove the additional one.

Comment: What is bootstrap.js?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, SSR. I don't know how to get jquery to load up first. Sorry, I'm new at Rails. I checked my views for additional calls to jquery but can't see any.

Comment: I did remove the redundant bootswatch as the menu works in my dev server without it. Bootswatch is a customizing plugin for bootstrap left over from the base template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redundant versions of jquery and bootstrap in my app/assets folder were clashing somehow during precompilation in production. I just deleted them from the directory, corrected my application.js, and ran another rake assets:precompile

That confused the problem. With the old scripts culled away, I was able to order jquery to load first, ( thanks SSR ).

Now both the responsive menu and the background carousel are playing nicely with jquery.

Incidentally, the base template was United by Bootswatch, and the bundled scripts I removed were;

```
bootstrap.js
jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

I'll be watching more carefully for conflicting scripts in downloaded templates from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Your application runs with two jQuery versions. rails provides latest jQuery version so no need to include extra versions. If you need to do so then replace

> //= require jquery

this line with your jQuery file

> //= require jquery-1.10.2.min.js

but remember your jQuery file should be in

> app/assets/javascript/

Your application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

this line should be end of the file but before body close tag.

Now on terminal fire this commands

```
cd /sites/<app_name>
rm public/assets -R
rake assets:precompile
```

Here you go :D

Comment: Thank you for all your excellent comments. Very informative indeed. I added your final turbolinks tracker, then I made the version require change for jquery and placed copies in the Vendor dir just in case. Still no dice.